# Kubernetes PVC volume mount

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running application on k8s.

My docker file is like :

```
FROM python:3.5 AS python-build
ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
```

in test directory, i am doing everything my files inside this test folder.

when i go inside pod and check file structure it's like `/var /usr /test /bin`

so i want to add whole folder test in pvc

in test file structure is like `/app /data /history`

so can i save add folder attach to pvc using mountpath?

is it possible two mountpath but one pvc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, you want to include your test directory as a mount path in your PVC. To answer that question, yes you can do it by providing it in the hostpath not the mount path. As explained in the documentation :-

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node’s filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.

and a mount path is -

> The location in pod where the volume should be mounted.

so, if from your host system you want to mount the \test folder you need to provide it in the pv like below

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/test"
```

and you can use this PV to claim a volume using pvc and use the **mountPath** to mount that volume into your pod.

To answer your second question, yes you can have multiple mount paths for a single PVC. An example of this which works is :-

```
    "containers": [
    {
        ...,
        "volumeMounts": [
         {
             "mountPath": "/mnt/1",
             "name": "v1",
             "subPath": "data/1"
         },
         {
             "mountPath": "/mnt/2",
             "name": "v1",
             "subPath": "data/2"
         }
       ]
    }
   ],
   ...,
   "volumes": [
       {
           "name": "v1",
           "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                "claimName": "testvolume"
           }
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for writing answer i am also trying the same form my side.i hope it will work giving the same name to mount path and assigning the same PVC to both mount point.  but can you tell me about `subpath` ???

Comment: i have did this in my config file `volumeMounts:
        - name: core-data
          mountPath: /app
        - name: core-data
          mountPath: /response-sheet-history
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: core-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: core-claim`

Comment: PVC going empty when i attach it.

Comment: you can find more information about subPath [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

Answer (score 2):

For mount points stuff, you don't have deal with `PVC`, but `PV`s and `volumeMounts` in deployment yaml. From [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

PVC

> A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It
>   is similar to a pod.

PV

> A PersistentVolume (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has
>   been provisioned by an administrator.

And yes, you can do that. Just Create PV(or Dont have to, depends on cluster configuration. PVs will create from PVCs) and specify `volumeMounts` in your deployment

Check out my yaml files in my repo

- PV Example with storage as `NFS`  - https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/pv/pv.yaml
- Deployement Example with `volumeMounts` - https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/spinnaker/minio.yaml#L55
- PVC Example incase if you need - https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/pv/pvc.yaml